# Extracting List of Friends on Facebook with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am currently trying to extract my list of friends through the FB SDK through PHP. This is the graph object returned to me.

```
Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNode Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [gender] => female [friends] => Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphEdge Object ( [request:protected] => Facebook\FacebookRequest Object ( [app:protected] => Facebook\FacebookApp Object ( [id:protected] => OMITTED [secret:protected] => OMITTED ) [accessToken:protected] => OMITTED [method:protected] => GET [endpoint:protected] => me/?fields=about%2Cbio%2Cbirthday%2Cgender%2Chometown%2Crelationship_status%2Cfriends [headers:protected] => Array ( [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded ) [params:protected] => Array ( ) [files:protected] => Array ( ) [eTag:protected] => [graphVersion:protected] => v2.5 ) [metaData:protected] => Array ( [summary] => Array ( [total_count] => 1001 ) ) [parentEdgeEndpoint:protected] => /10206890247526057/friends [subclassName:protected] => [items:protected] => Array ( ) ) [id] => 10206890247526057 ) )
```

I am trying to extract the data in this object:

```
[friends] => Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphEdge Object
```

And trying to do this via PHP. I get the result above with the following code:

```
$req2 = $fb->get("me/fields=about,bio,birthday,gender,hometown,relationship_status,friends");
$all = $req2->getGraphObject();
print_r($all);
```

I am having trouble getting to the bones of what I am trying to extract and that is the array of friend IDs and names. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Hi, did you access the items:protected?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the protected items property of a GraphNode object by using the `all()` method (it's an inherited method from the `Collection` class, that GraphNode extends).

This will simply return the items as an array.

I hope this will help!